# How to use crosstab for multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, crosstab

I need help using crosstab on the df below.

```
    a       b       c
-------------------------
|   a   |  None |   c   |
|   a   |   b   |  None |
|  None |   b   |   c   |
|   a   |  None |  None |
|  None |  None |  None |
```

I want to pull rows where more than letter is specified (a&b, a&c, b&c) i.e. rows 1-3. I believe the easiest way to do this is through crosstab (I know I'll get a count but can I also view the rows through this method?). I want to avoid having to write a lengthy 'or' statement to acheive this.

Desired Output:

```
    a       b       c
-------------------------
|   a   |  None |   c   |
|   a   |   b   |  None |
|  None |   b   |   c   |
```

Comment: Please add your expected output to the problem. This is possible, just depends what  you need in the end.

Comment: @ALollz updated.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looking for crosstab, just check the number of non-nulls using `notnull`:

```
df[df.notnull().sum(1).gt(1)]
```

```
     a    b    c
0    a  NaN    c
1    a    b  NaN
2  NaN    b    c
```

---

Or you can use `dropna`:

```
t = 2
df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1] - t + 1)
```

```
     a    b    c
0    a  NaN    c
1    a    b  NaN
2  NaN    b    c
```

Comment: This is not the whole dataframe however. How can I perform this only on these 3 columns? I technically have a column 'd' as well. For the sake of the question, just decided to keep it as simple as I could.

Comment: @user10939484 `df[df.loc[:,'a':'c'].notna().sum(1).ge(2)]`